# Who has the authorization to remove a coach in Football?

Tags: football, english-premier-league

Through many football season I have seen (Premier League), the manager has been usually removed by the club boss. But sometimes I have seen that the club board has been responsible.

So I want to know, who is normally authorized to sack the manager in an individual football team?

Answer (score 2):

The decision to remove the manager is never done by just one person. A football club big enough to be in the Premier League will be run by a board of directors. So it will be the board's decision to sack the manager. Some clubs also include the major shareholders in such meetings as they are directly invested in the success of the club.

Comment: With the exception of some crazy owner maybe here and there :)

Comment: Hmm, can you think of any Premier League clubs run my Russian Oligarchs or Pan Asian Tycoons. In principal, any majority share holder has the power to sack anybody at the club, within the bounds of employment and contract law.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same as for any other employment: the manager is an employee of the club, and the club can decide to relieve any employee of their duties at any time<sup>1</sup>. Which specific people make that decision isn't something which is regulated by the football authorities - the manager is the person who is nominated by the club to be the manager of the team for that match.

1. Employment law is of course more complicated than that, but that's the gist of it.